# C# - How to use DirectorySecurity.SetOwner() ? I'm having troubles

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I'm having troubles figuring out the `SetOwner()` method.
In my case, I've created an user in Active Directory by code, then, I create a folder for the user.

It all works fine, but I cannot set the newly created user as the owner of the folder.
I'm not a C# guru, so I'm having troubles to understand the `DirectorySecurity.SetOwner()` method. Can anyone please help me out?

Here is the code that creates the folder, sets the rights like i want it, but I also need to set the user as the owner.

```
string pathIntern = @"\\11fil01\brukar\" + user.UserName;

System.IO.DirectoryInfo diIntern = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathIntern);

diIntern.Create();

DirectorySecurity dsecIntern = diIntern.GetAccessControl();

FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(user.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.None | nheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);

dsecIntern.SetAccessRule(rule);
diIntern.SetAccessControl(dsecIntern);
//dsecIntern.SetOwner(heeeeelp);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
string pathIntern = @"\\11fil01\brukar\" + user.UserName;               
DirectoryInfo diIntern       = new DirectoryInfo(pathIntern);
DirectorySecurity dsecIntern = diIntern.GetAccessControl();
IdentityReference newUser    = new NTAccount(domain + @”\” + username);
dsecIntern.SetOwner(newUser);
FileSystemAccessRule permissions = new FileSystemAccessRule(newUser,FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
dsecIntern.AddAccessRule(permissions);
diIntern.SetAccessControl(dsecIntern);
```

You can see this link too
[Create, Read, Update Active Directory Users with C#](http://gazishaheen.wordpress.com/create-read-update-actide-directory-users-with-c/)

Bye.