# C# save directory permissions

Tags: c#, permissions, file-permissions, directory-permissions

I've been trying to find a way to store permissions on a directory. I am currently using SetACL to help. If I could change ownership on directories/registry without it that would be preferred, but that's a different story. An example is this:

Check current owner and permissions for that owner. Change to permissions and owner on button click > change it back to the original when another button is clicked.

To save the question of why, my team does technical support. We remote into a computer, perform our t/s and leave. We need to be able to change permissions then revert it back the way it was.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `System.Management` and `System.Management.Instrumentation` namespaces, you can use the `Directory.GetAccessControl` method to get who has access to a folder.  You can then use the `AddAccessRule` and `SetAccessControl` methods to actually apply your new permissions.   When you are done, you could remove your new permissions.  Here is an article that walks you through how to change permissions on a folder:

http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

The basic code this author uses is as follows:

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(yourFolderHere);

// Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
// current security settings.
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

// Builds a new user string for who we want to give permissions to
string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + yourUserName; 

// Creates the permissions to apply 
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, 
                                  FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

// Set the new access settings. 
myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);

// Showing a Success Message
MessageBox.Show("Permissions Altered Successfully");
}
```

As for setting the owner, here is a good SO article on how to do so:

[C# - How to use DirectorySecurity.SetOwner() ? I'm having troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435543/c-how-to-use-directorysecurity-setowner-im-having-troubles)

However, if you wanted to set the owner to be someone else (since I would assume you don't need to assign ownership permissions to a user when they already have access to assign ownership permissions), this above method won't work I don't believe.  I have found documentation on how to set the owner to be someone other than yourself.  Here is the link:

http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/setting-the-owner-of-files-and-directories-in-c/

Comment: BiggsTRC, I will test out what you just posted. Thank you for providing so much information! Project that is due Monday morning so thanks again for getting back so quickly

Comment: @John Andrews - Glad to be of help.  Go ahead and give a shout out if you need help or get stuck somewhere.  I want to see you succeed.

Comment: Ok, I've got it so that I can change the Owner and set permissions. Two things: 1 when I set the permissions for an account, it just adds another in with "Special Permissions" and 2 I still can't store the permissions. Tried and tried but it's not working.

Comment: Here's what I've got so far...still don't have a way to save it, but if inheritance is set then I get a user full permissions, remove then permissions and reset inheritance. Work around for storing I guess.

Comment: @John Andrews - Here is a link with an example that might help you. It looks like their examples do exactly what you want to do:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx